# React native - iOs - Push Notification doesn't work on iOs <= 10.3.3 and below

Tags: react-native, ios10, react-native-firebase

I'm integrating react native app and firebase to push notification.
I'm using react-native-firebase at https://rnfirebase.io/
It's working fine on iOs 11 but It doesn't work on iOs 10 when app is closed/killed (only work once app is background/foreground)
Do you guys have any idea/solution for this one ???

Comment: have you tried the `firebase` lib? use `npm install --save --save-exact firebase@5.0.2`

Comment: @Khajavi: Thanks your feedback. Yes, it's already in the my app. It's working fine on iOs 11. But iOs 10 it's not working once app is closed/killed

Comment: are you using a iOS simulator?

Comment: @Khajavi: No, i'm using my phone - iPhone 6+ running ios 10.2

Answer (score 0):

Seems it's a bug as you can see in [this issue](https://github.com/invertase/react-native-firebase/issues/1179)!

Also as [docs](https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/messaging/introduction#Data-only-messages) says:

[image: rnfirebase-docs-notification]

Comment: Thanks for feeback. But i don't think so.. Docs says this:
- App in foreground: onNotification triggered
- App in background: onNotificationDisplayed triggered if content_available set to true 
onNotificationOpened triggered if the notification is tapped
- App closed: getInitialNotification is populated if the notification is tapped and opens the app

Comment: @Shine you asked for killed-app scenario, which is mentioned `Received when app is next time opened`

Comment: @Khajavi: it's Data-only messages type, we are not using it.
We are using Notification Message from Firebase -> please see docs here: https://rnfirebase.io/docs/v4.2.x/notifications/introduction